# Cannot find module 'ts-transformer-keys'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

Tags: typescript

I want to use [ts-transformer-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-keys) in my typescript project `"typescript": "^4.5.5"`. So I added this dependency to the typescript `package.json`:

```
"ts-transformer-keys": "^0.4.3",
```

and added this to `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
"plugins": [
      { "transform": "ts-transformer-keys/transformer" }
]
```

but when I import the `ts-transformer-keys` in the current project:

```
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';
```

shows error:

```
Cannot find module 'ts-transformer-keys'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?ts(2792)
```

Why did this happen? What should I do to fix this problem? I have already run the yarn command. The node version is `16.13.2`.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

this error message tell how to fix this problem, the typescript default module resolution is classic, this would not search from `node_modules`. That why tell you did not found the module that in the `node_modules` folder. more info you can read from here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html, so fix your problem, try add this config in the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"moduleResolution":"node",
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to add this to the `"compilerOptions"` section of `tsconfig.json`. So the result is ```{ "compilerOptions": { ... , "moduleResolution": "node" }, ... }```

Comment: As specified by @rovyko add it to `jsconfig.json` if you are using *React.js*

Comment: it doesn't work for now

Comment: To be completely accurate, moduleResolution default value when `compilerOptions.module` equals to `commonJS`, is `node` otherwise the default value is `classic`.

Comment: I got the error `..set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext'`. After adding `node` to tsconfig.json as pointed out here and in the comment of @rovyko it works.

Answer (score 22):

After you added `"moduleResolution": "node"`, if you still get the error try to close vs code e reopen.

This works for me after adding ts to an existing nextjs project.

Comment: Whew, restarting vscode was required for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: i spent whole day just to understand i had to reopen vscode ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️

Comment: Works for Visual studio IDE too

Answer (score -1):

It can also happen to js (not ts) projects, in that case, you can use a `jsconfig.json` at project root, and put the same content in it as you'd put in `tsconfig.json`.

To quickly locate `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json`, look at the status bar of VSCode, there's a thing that looks like `{} JavaScript` or `{} TypeScript`, hover over the `{}`.